# Куда захостить питоновский скрипт?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Есть бот на третьем питоне, нужен бесплатный сервис для запуска этого самого бота. На сколько я знаю в google app engine доступен только 2.x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обратите внимание на [pythonanywhere.com](http://pythonanywhere.com), там поддерживаются обе ветки.

Answer (score 2):

Могу предложить перед выкладкой преобразовать скрипты утилитой [3to2](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/3to2).